# How can I get Text from Js to Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, speech-recognition

```
<script>
    function voice(){
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.lang = "en-GB";
        recognition.onresult = function(event){
            console.log(event);
            document.getElementById("speechto").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        }
        recognition.start();


    }

</script>
```

I am making language translator web-app. And in above code, it takes input from the user using mic and print that in textarea in eng language. So I want this text in my python so that I can translate it and print it on another textarea. But i dont know how can I get that text from the js into my python code.
any soln?

Comment: Of course there are solutions.  You use an AJAX request to send a `post` request to your backend and await the result.    I like using `jQuery.ajax`, but there are other libraries.

Comment: but I dont know how can I do that? You have any soln?

Comment: Or you can tell me if I can take input from the user using mic in python language so that js wont be used.

Comment: *I dont know how can I do that?*  -- That's what Google is for.  AJAX is a large topic.  You need to do some reading.  Python can read the microphone on the computer where it is running, but if your user is running a web browser on another computer, then there's no connection.

Answer (score 0):

Where is "your python"? I'm assuming this is on a browser over a network. You gotta set up a webserver (in python) to listen to network responses. Try webpy for a simple solution: https://webpy.org/.

You'll have to set up a URL endpoint to respond to POST requests. More info here: https://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#getpost.

And lastly, you'll have to set up your Javascript to send the post request and to use the response from your server to edit the textarea. You can use the JS fetch API to send the post request and handle the response from there.

Good luck hooking everything up

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using flask as that is tagged in your question. You need to establish a route to execute your python code and run your flask app which should listen to some TCP port on your computer (by default flask seems to use port 5000).

Then on your js code you can use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) method to send the text to that port. For example:

```
fetch('http://locahost:5000/{your flask route goes here}', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    },
    body: {text you want to send goes here},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than using python just to do a translation, why not to use a simple javascript translate function?

```
    var translate = async (t,src,dst) => {
        var tt = new Promise(function(resolve) {
            var i=0, len=0, r='', tt='';
            const url = 'https://clients5.google.com/translate_a/';
            var params = 'single?dj=1&dt=t&dt=sp&dt=ld&dt=bd&client=dict-chrome-ex&sl='+src+'&tl='+dst+'&q='+t;
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var response;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
                    response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    for (var i = 0, len = response.sentences?.length; i < len; i++) {
                        var r=(((response.sentences[i].trans).replace('}/g','')).replace(')/g','')).replace('\%20/g', ' ');
                        r=((r.replace('}','')).replace(')','')).replace('\%20/g', ' ');
                        tt += r;
                    }
                    if (tt.includes('}'||')'||'%20')) {
                        tt=((tt.replace('}/g','')).replace(')/g','')).replace('\%20/g', ' ');
                    }
                    resolve(tt);
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open('GET', url+params, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange();
        });
        return await tt;
    }
```